# Any better way to make a object into another object in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
Oldobject = {'name':'Joe','age':12};
newObject = {'address':'XXX'};
```

I want to get result like :

```
{'name':'Joe','age':12,'address':'XXX' }
```

I use

```
Oldobject.address = newObject
```

Is there any graceful way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var property in Oldobject) { 
    newObject[property] = Oldobject[property]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for... in` loop, like:

```
    for( var property in newObject ){
        OldObject[property] = newObject[property]
    }
```

This will put all of the stuff from `newObject` into `oldObject`.